# Windows Batch Date Time

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file

When working with batch I used the variables `%date%` and `%time%` to get the date and the time.

Somewhere between the lines I wanted to change `%date%` and `%time%` because I wanted to use a different format, I wasn't aware of other ways to do so, so in my script I had the lines:

```
@set date=/*something*/
@set time=/*something*/
```

Here's a script which shows my problem: The first time it shows the date and time and then it shows `/*something*/`

```
@echo %date%
@echo %time%

@set date=/*something*/
@set time=/*something*/
```

How can I set it back to the date and time?

I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "date="
set "time="
```

`date` and `time` are *magic variables* - set by the system **but** `set`ting them to any value overrides the system-supplied value.